# Reflection form create instance with Generic interface

Tags: c#, generics

I have a generic selection for my interface like this:

```
        public interface IMyInterface{
              void ok();
        }

        var maps = (from t in types
                    from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                    where typeof(IMyInterface).IsAssignableFrom(t) &&
                          !t.IsAbstract &&
                          !t.IsInterface
                    select (IMyInterface)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToArray();
```

But I changed my interface to generic,

```
        public interface IMyInterface<T>{
              void ok<T>();
        }

        var maps = (from t in types 
                    from i in t.GetInterfaces()
                    where i.IsGenericType 
                        && i.GetGenericTypeDefinition() == typeof(IMyInterface<>)
                        && !t.IsAbstract
                        && !t.IsInterface
                        select ???????????????????????????????
                    ).ToArray();
```

but now the casting is not working.

```
        select (IMyInterface<>)Activator.CreateInstance(t)).ToArray();
```

Gives build error for casting.

Comment: Your method declaration is wrong, too bad you omitted it.  It has to be generic on type T,.  Then use `IMyInterface<T>` instead of IMyInterface<>.  Both IMyInterface and T need to be declared in an assembly that is referenced by both projects.  Fairly unlikely to be a correct approach.

Answer (score 0):

`IMyInterface<T>` is *not* a `IMyInterface<>`, therefore the cast is not valid. The compiler just protects you from finding this at runtime, because you can *never* have a value of type `GenericType<>` in C# - non-reified generic types are only used for reflection.

Note how `typeof(IMyInterface<>).IsAssignableFrom(typeof(IMyInterface<string>))` returns `false`. The two types are completely different and only share a common generic definition, the same as `List<int>` and `List<string>` are two different types that only share a common generic definition. C# generics aren't Java generics.

There is no common type you can use to encompass both `List<string>` and `List<int>`, just like there's not common type you can use for your `IMyInterface<A>` and `IMyInterface<B>`. Either make sure everything is properly generic, or make another interface that isn't generic and that `IMyInterface<T>` implements.

Comment: @bookmarker That doesn't really change anything. You're still trying to cast to a "not a real type" type.